# Objective c division of two ints

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to produce a a float by dividing two `int`s in my program. Here is what I'd expect:

1 / 120 = 0.00833

Here is the code I'm using:

```
float a = 1 / 120;
```

However it doesn't give me the result I'd expect. When I print it out I get the following:

```
inf
```

Comment: How are you printing float value a to console ? Unless you are printing NSLog(@"inf"); or printf("inf"); you can't get inf printed on console.

Comment: @0x8badf00d: Yes, you (probably) can: `printf("%g\n", 1.0 / 0.0);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do the following

```
float a = 1./120.
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify that you want to use floating point math.

There's a few ways to do this:

- If you really are interested in dividing two constants, you can specify that you want floating point math by making the **first** constant a float (or double). All it takes is a decimal point.

  ```
  float a = 1./120;
  ```

  You don't need to make the second constant a float, though it doesn't hurt anything.
- Frankly, this is pretty easy to miss so I'd suggest adding a trailing zero and some spacing.

  ```
  float a = 1.0 / 120;
  ```
- If you really want to do the math with an integer variable, you can type cast it:

  ```
  float a = (float)i/120;
  ```

Answer (score 5):

```
float a = 1/120;
float b = 1.0/120;
float c = 1.0/120.0;
float d = 1.0f/120.0f;

NSLog(@"Value of A:%f B:%f C:%f D:%f",a,b,c,d);

Output: Value of A:0.000000 B:0.008333 C:0.008333 D:0.008333
```

For float variable a : int / int yields integer which you are assigning to float and printing it so 0.0000000

For float variable b: float / int yields float, assigning to float and printing it  0.008333

For float variable c: float / float yields float, so 0.008333

Last one is more precise float. Previous ones are of type double: all floating point values are stored as double data types unless the value is followed by an 'f' to specifically specify a float rather than as a double.

Answer (score 4):

In C (and therefore also in Objective-C), expressions are almost always evaluated without regard to the context in which they appear.

The expression `1 / 120` is a division of two `int` operands, so it yields an `int` result.  Integer division truncates, so `1 / 120` yields `0`.  The fact that the result is used to initialize a `float` object doesn't change the way `1 / 120` is evaluated.

This can be counterintuitive at times, especially if you're accustomed to the way calculators generally work (they usually store all results in floating-point).

As the other answers have said, to get a result close to 0.00833 (which can't be represented exactly, BTW), you need to do a floating-point division rather than an integer division, by making one or both of the operands floating-point.  If one operand is floating-point and the other is an integer, the integer operand is converted to floating-point first; there is no direct floating-point by integer division operation.

Note that, as @0x8badf00d's comment says, the result should be `0`.  Something else must be going wrong for the printed result to be `inf`.  If you can show us more code, preferably a small complete program, we can help figure that out.

(There are languages in which integer division yields a floating-point result.  Even in those languages, the evaluation isn't necessarily affected by its context.  Python version 3 is one such language; C, Objective-C, and Python version 2 are not.)