# Float returns zero after decimal point ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to show exact decimal points.

```
float value =26/5;
```

When i logged value it shows 5.00000 i need it as 5.2 exactly. I have also used double value nothing helps.

Comment: That's the defined behaviour of integer division in C (from which Objective-C is derived). See for example [What is the behavior of integer division in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c).

Comment: Or this older Q&A:  [Objective c division of two ints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459351/objective-c-division-of-two-ints)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float value = 26.0 / 5.0;` will do. In your code, the numbers are treated as integers so the division supplies an integer result.

Answer (score 4):

In `float value = 26/5;` both the numerator and denominator are integers so integer math will be used and integer math produces an integer by rounding down which is then converted to a floating point number.

Make one or both floating point values and you will get a floating point result:

```
float value = 26/5.0;
```

or

```
float value = 26.0/5;
```

or

```
float value = 26.0/5.0;
```

or you can use casting instead of changing the numbers floating point:

```
float value = (float)26/(float)5;
```

Note that 26.0/5.0 does not produce exactly 5.2 because 5.2 can not be exactly represented in floating point, the value will be something similar to 5.19999980926513671875. This may present problems.

Example:

```
float value = 26.0/5.0;
NSLog(@"value: %.20f", value);
```

Output:

> value: 5.19999980926513671875

While a lower precision display will look correct:

```
NSLog(@"value: %f", value);
```

Output:

> value: 5.200000

If you want to only display two decimal points:

```
NSLog(@"value: %.2f", value);
```

Output:

> value: 5.20

Comment: @Burhanuddin Sunelwala Please add your `NSDecimalNumber` link as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add .0 after the numbers as

```
float value =26.0/5.0;
```

which will work as float, without .0 they are treated as integers.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to log it or print it, use this: `[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:someFloatValue] stringValue];`
As user "return true" said, the value is exact, but if you want exact decimals to be *printed or logged as string*, you can use the above code.
And don't forget to use 26.0 / 5.0 so you get a decimal.